# Error:-java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-developer-api

I am not able to create intent activity on button and textview. My application is crashed when I try to click on button or textview

**LoginActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.nupur.kezin_king;

/**
 * Created by Nupur on 8/1/2016.
 */

        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import butterknife.BindView;
        import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    @BindView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @BindView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.link_signup) TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this); //for using @BindView
//Event on Login Button
        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
//Event on SignUp TextView
        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
               // Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
               // startActivity(intent);
              //  LoginActivity.this.getIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login");

        if (!validate()) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        }

        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // On complete call either onLoginSuccess or onLoginFailed
                        onLoginSuccess();
                         onLoginFailed();
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                }, 5000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                LoginActivity.this.getIntent();
                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
              // this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        LoginActivity.this.getIntent();
       // finish();
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

**SignUpActivity.java**
This is My SignUp page which I want to intent on the textview click event textview id=link_signup

```
package com.example.nupur.kezin_king;

/**
 * Created by Nupur on 8/1/2016.
 */

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";

    //@BindView(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
    EditText _nameText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    @BindView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @BindView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
    @BindView(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signup();
            }
        });

        _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

        if (!validate()) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }

        _signupButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                        // depending on success
                        onSignupSuccess();
                        // onSignupFailed();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);
    }


    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
            _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _nameText.setError(null);
        }

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"


    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Login"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**activity_signup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!--  Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:hint="Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Create Account"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Android:- AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nupur.kezin_king">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error which I am getting is :-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nupur.kezin_king, PID: 16544
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nupur.kezin_king/com.example.nupur.kezin_king.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at com.example.nupur.kezin_king.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16544 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

**styles.xml:-**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
    <style name="AppTheme_Dark_Dialog" parent="AppTheme_Dark_Dialog"/>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppTheme"/>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you post your appTheme too

Comment: Can you publish your styles page? (usually "styles.xml")

Comment: I added the style.xml ..